# ABRecordSetValue in IOS 5 Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, abrecord

I am a newbie and I have a question with ABRecordSetValue in Xcode 4.2.  I have this code:

```
        ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, lastName, &anError);
```

But, I keep on receiving this error message:

Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') is disallowed with ARC

I have the 'lastName' field as a NSString. What is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As third parameter expects CFTypeRef, we can do below casting.

Try this:

```
ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (CFStringRef)lastName, &anError);
```

Comment: Thank you @saran.  I had to use a bridge however, but thanks again.


ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)lastName, &anError);

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar error (iOS 5.0) I needed to add `__bridge`

```
ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonLastNameProperty, __bridge CFStringRef)lastName);
```